Removable insulation for portable A/C in Florida
We live in a condo in Florida, where it is extremely humid and hot.  We have central A/C, but I need the bedroom to be really cold at night, so we purchased a portable A/C for the bedroom (it is not allowed to install window units or mini-splits).
The portable A/C works great, but heat and humidity seeps in and the humidity in the bedroom is often close to 80% (it should be 60% or less to prevent mold).  This is a dual-hose A/C, installed using the hose-mounting kit and some adhesive foam:

Part of the problem is that I need to be able to remove the A/C from the window and close it whenever there is a hurricane heading our way.
Any suggestions for how I can better insulate this, so that it does not seep in heat and moisture?  Perhaps some removable spray-insulation foam (if that exists)?

Not sure if the installation kit came that way, but increasing the separation between the two hoses  means less likelihood of drawing in already heated expelled air and causing your AC unit to work harder trying to cool even hotter than ambient warm air.

As Delphic suggests, putting in a vertical separator between the screen and the insert so exhaust air from the one hose cannot be easily sucked into the intake hose is a good idea; my dual-hose model has such a separator built in.

Re: "heat and humidity seeps in" - where does it seep in? There is often a gap between the bottom  inner window and the outer window at the top of the inner window when it is partially raised. A strip of foam pressed into that gap should help.

The installation kit came with the unit.  I might have to get one custom made with greater separation.  Re. gaps: I have checked for gaps and handled one with foam, but cannot find any other obvious ones.  I just know that the room gets more warm and humid daytime (when the A/C is not running) than it did before I installed the A/C.  I assume that it could be many small gaps that adds up.  Also, I will probably get insulation sleeves for the hoses.

Piggybacking on the earlier suggestions, you could get a pair of 90º elbows and fasten them to the exterior of the insert, facing opposite directions.  That'll prevent air recirculation.  What's the exterior side of the insert look like?

@Huesmann unfortunately that would be too visible and I would be made to remove it (it is in the HOA contract to not have anything in the windows - I am not even sure if my current installation is allowed, but it is not very visible from the outside, so will hopefully not be a problem)

To see if air leakage around the window area is the problem, you could try installing heat shrink “winter” window sealing removable clear film and see if that cuts down on the problem.

@Armand that might be a good idea!  Thanks.
